# How to get gvx cookies from Google Voice in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, rest, google-voice

I need to get back gvx cookies from Google Voice login post request in order to do direct access number calling. From my understanding, Google Voice will set a gvx cookies on the client identified as a mobile device (I have set the correct user-agent) once logged in.

I can successfully log in using this URL Post Request:

```
https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?ltmpl=mobile&btmpl=mobile&Email=username%40gmail.com&Passwd=mypassword&service=grandcentral&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fvoice%2Fm&timeStmp=&secTok=&signIn=Sign+in
```

and USER-Agent:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8H7 Safari/6533.18.5
```

Objective-C code:

```
NSString *data = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ltmpl=mobile&btmpl=mobile&Email=%@&Passwd=%@&service=grandcentral&continue=%@&timeStmp=&secTok=&signIn=Sign+in", self.user.urlEncoded, self.password.urlEncoded, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.google.com/voice/m"].urlEncoded ];

if (captchaResponse && captchaToken) {
    data = [data stringByAppendingFormat: @"&logintoken=%@&logincaptcha=%@",
            captchaToken.urlEncoded, 
            captchaResponse.urlEncoded];
}

NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [data UTF8String] length: [data length]];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: LOGIN_URL_STRING];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: url];

[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody: requestData];
[request setValue: USER_AGENT_IPHONE forHTTPHeaderField: USER_AGENT_HEADER];

NSURLResponse *resp = nil;
NSError *err = nil;

NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: &resp error: &err];

self.general = [dict objectForKey: RAW_DATA];

    if (self.general) {
        self.rnrSe = [self discoverRNRSE];
    }

    [self fetchSettings];

    NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
    NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieJar = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    for (cookie in [cookieJar cookies]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", cookie);
    }
```

All i got back from cookies are 3 names:

```
GALX - with some random characters and numbers value
GAPS - with some random characters and numbers value
S - with value: "grandcentral=xxxxxx..xxxx"
```

I should get back a lot more in Cookies such as:

`HSID, SSID, APISID, PREF, NID` And most importantly `gvx` cookie. That's what I'm looking for.

How do I get the gvx cookies?